# cuda driver installation failed (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia

I've strictly followed the CUDA 10.0 installation process mentioned here: 
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html
but I found it doesn't describe the X server issues, because when I execute it in my Ubuntu14.10 environment it report I need stop X Server before installing CUDA10.0, 
The following is the error message:
.....
Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
It appears that an X server is running. Please exit X before installation. If you're sure that X is not running, but are getting this error, please delete any X lock files in /tmp.

===========

## = Summary =

Driver: Installation Failed
Toolkit: Installation skipped
Samples: Installation skipped

Answer (score 1):

assuming X is not running, according to **If you're sure that X is not running, but are getting this error, please delete any X lock files in /tmp.**

I used " sudo rm /tmp/.X*-lock ".
It was the solution in my case. *simply*!